# C++ and writing enum values into Windows registry

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am writing a function as follows:

```
bool abc::GetLoggingStatus() {
    //true or false is returned
    int value;
    if (regKey->HasValue("LoggingStatus")) {
        regKey->QueryValue("LoggingStatus", &value);
        if (value == 1)
            return true; //no logging possible
        else
            return false;
    }
    regKey->SetValue("LoggingStatus", 1);
    return true;
}
```

Logging level is defined as:

```
typedef enum {
    Entry,
    Exit,
    Debug,
    Warning,
    Notification,
    Error
} TYPE;
```

What I need if I select 1 the levels for logging must be shown namely debug,error ... In regedit and if 0 nothing should be shown and logging be disabled.

Comment: `if (value = 1)` should probably be `if (value == 1)`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to write the name of the enum instead of the value? So "Entry" instead of 0?

Comment: @BenRuijlwhat i want is user goes into registry , goes to location and  needs to set logging on /off 1 stands for logging on , if user selects that then he must be able to select the logging level as debug error notification or warning and if he selects 0 all these options must be diabled

Comment: So you want the enum to be shown inside regedit?

Comment: @Asafalong with the logging on / off option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create dropdown menus in regedit, but what you can do is create a new entry called `LoggingLevel`. This entry is ignored if `LoggingStatus` is 0. `LoggingLevel` is a string defining the level.

If you want to convert this string back to an enum, the easiest way is to create a map from string to your Enum type:

```
std::map<std::string, TYPE> typeMap;
typeMap["Warning"] = Warning;
...
```

In your code you query the logging level:

```
char* level;
regKey->QueryValue("LoggingLevel", level);
TYPE theLevel = typeMap[level];
```

Of course you need to do appropriate error checking.

**edit**

You should add two function to get the log settings, `shouldLog()` and `getLevel()`.
The log function would then look like:

```
void log(Logger* logger, TYPE type, string sClassName, string sMethodName, string sMessage = "") { 
if (!logger || !abc::shouldLog()) {
   return;
}


TYPE curLevel = abc::getLevel();
bool shouldLog = false;

if (type == Warning && (curLevel == All || curLevel == Warning) ...) {
  shouldLog = true;
}

if (shouldLog) {logger->WriteEntry(sClassName, sMethodName); }

}
```

If you want to avoid complicated if-structures, you could also try and map the enums to a value and compare that. For example Warning = 1 and ALL = 0. Then you can check if `curLevel < type` to see if the logger should log.

Comment: @BenRuiji:i am writing this in a class , i have some logging statements in other class , how do i associate this with the logging statements also along with this if a user selects top level debug , he must see debug notify error statements all

Comment: In this class, which should probably be a singleton, you have to define a function `log` that takes the message and the log level as an argument. Then you can check in this function if the log level is high enough to be printed. All the other classes should call the `log` function of this class.

Comment: i have a log function as:
static int log(Logger* logger, TYPE type, string sClassName, string sMethodName, string sMessage = "") {
        if (logger) {
            switch (type) {
                case Entry: logger->WriteEntry(sClassName, sMethodName);
                    return 0;

Comment: I am so confused at the moment, the logging class is being used in the common.cpp where i am writing code for the should log() and getlevel() and the log function is in logger.h which is used in common.h and again common.h is include in common.cpp so how does i compare

Comment: the enum is declared public in the logger class in logger.h